# publish_actions to upload a photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook [permissions doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/publishing/) states that if an app is granted the publish_actions permission, it can upload photos to the user's albums. But when I try to post to /{userId}/photos, I get a `(OAuthException - #102) A user access token is required to request this resource.` error. Note that posting to /{userId}/feed works though.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you need `user_photos` as well...

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a GET request to /user/photos?

Comment: @Lix: just tried that, same result I'm afraid...

Comment: @Igy: the doc explicitly mentions the upload of photos

Comment: Are you sure you're not making a GET request which is returning that error? Also, are you sure you're using a user access token? the error implies you're not - a call to /me/permissions should tell you what permissions you have from the user

Comment: @Igy: no I'm 100% sure I'm issuing a POST. I'm using an app access token and not a user one, as my understanding from the doc is that the app has the right to upload the photo to the user. And checking /{userId}/permissions with an app access token shows the right permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the error message, you need to use a user access token to make the call, not the app access token

Comment: You're probably right... Do you know any reliable doc showing the actions that the app can perform on the user's account without a user access token?

Comment: I think it's just feed publish, open graph publish and accessing basic data - i'm surprised those haven't yet been removed  and changed to require an active session, but certainly photo uploads need a valid session

Comment: You mean that all OpenGraph operations may require a user session in the future? So an app like Tumblr that posts your new articles to your wall will need to get a user access_token every time?

Comment: Don't tumblr already do that? Unless they still have a majority of users with the old offline_access permission, they need users to come back once every 60 days to keep the tokens active

Comment: I see, and as many users are constantly logged in Facebook, getting a new token is probably a transparent action

Answer (score -1):

Acording to https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/... you will need `publish_stream` permissions. I tried the first example and it worked for me.

Comment: This example uses a user access token ; I would like to post to a registered user using my app access token.

Comment: And where do you **specify** this in your question? It is necessary to vote me down for this?